# Allow Wordpress installed with Docker on Azure to be embeded as iframe

Tags: wordpress, azure, .htaccess, iframe, header

I created a simple webapp container with the image wordpress:latest on linux on azure.

Everything works fine. Now I tried to embed this website in a website which I am working on running on my localhost:port.

Since I don't have access to SSH to edit the wp-config.php or .htaccess (it's anyways in the docker container) I installed the plugin wp-htaccess-editor to have access to the .htaccess (it really has access... I did changes and checked with another plugin..)

```
# BEGIN HttpHeaders
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN HttpHeaders" and "END HttpHeaders" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "^(.+)$" CORS=$0
  </IfModule>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS}e env=CORS
  <FilesMatch "\.(php|html)$">
    Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://192.....:5174"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END HttpHeaders
```

But I still get the error:

```
Refused to display 'http://goofyPage.azurewebsites.net' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

But it is not true that x-frame-options is set to sameorigin.. it is set allow-from myLocalIP. **=> Somehow can it be that nginx overrides this option? since when I check the header data it is really still "sameorigin"...**

What are my options to make this work? Should I add the header option also on Azure on my webApp->configuration->Application settings??

When I check https://goofyPage.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env#httpHeaders

**AppSettings**
Header = set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM http://192...:5174
...

**Environment variables**
APPSETTING_Header = set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM http://192....:5174
Header = set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM http://192.....:5174

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options says allow-from is anyways not allowed? Why should this not be allowed anymore if I am the owner of both websites and want to do this??

Comment: dear diary today I learnt a lot: set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM is deprecated and should not be used anymore... instead just use Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors <source>;